# Example of two analytic functions that differ at countably infinity many point

Tags: examples-counterexamples, analyticity

$\displaystyle f_1(x) = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ and $f_2(x) = x^{n-1} + \cdots + 1$
have the same values except at $x=1$ (where $f_1$ fails to be analytic ).

Is there an example of two analytic function that differ at infinitely many countable point?

Comment: Is this real analyticity or complex? Are you requiring both functions to be analytic everywhere?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation

Comment: @CameronWilliams : is it even possible with the case analytic everywhere? I didnt think it would, but that is not a proof of course

Comment: @Arjang I just wanted to be sure. I had a feeling you meant that, but sometimes people ask ill-posed questions.

Comment: Note that one often disregards removable singularities, so that $z\mapsto z^2/z$ is regarded as entire, as is $z\mapsto (\sin z)/ z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. An easy example, following your lead, is that $\cos z$ is analytic everywhere; $1/(1/\cos z)$ is necessarily the same everywhere where $1/\cos z$ is defined: but it's not defined for $\cos z = 0,$ which only happens on the real line at points $z = n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$, which is countably infinite.

More generally for any $f(x)$ define $g(x) \in \mathbb C - \mathbb N$ to be equal to $f(x)$ for all points which it is defined for; points in $\mathbb N$ are not in its domain, so it is undefined there and fails to be analytic.